# Website Forwarder not Forwarding-- but is?

Tags: tcp, udp

This problem might be a lot simpler than you guys are used to, with an equally simple solution but I'm just not seeing it.

So we have a redirect site called:

*delphonbenefits.com*

which redirects to a site called:

*pcms.plansource.com*

On everybody else's network this redirect works. However, on my network it does not. Is there anything that would prevent my network from allowing this redirect? Let me know if you guys can help!

Here are some DNS reports that may or may not be relevant:
[image]

[image]

Comment: is this redirect occurred through your firewall , router or the ISP . are you mean by MY NETWORK you internal network .?

Answer (score 1):

The redirect occurs within HTTP, so if you can reach the web server, it would not be blocked.  You need to determine the source of the redirect as it may come from web server, load balancer, firewall, etc.  You also need to confirm you're getting the same or equivalent functioning IP for the host via DNS.  Outside networks are most likely not hitting same devices as when you access the web server.  For example, you may be landing directly on server while your load balancer or other device is sending redirects for external users.  The redirect might even be occurring for you, but the site you're redirecting to is blocked for your path.  *More details from you still help troubleshoot this.*